# Format a ruby decimal to string without leading zero (".123")

Tags: ruby

I want something like `.725` as String. Right now, I use `%.3f` but it shows the leading zero as `0.725`. In summary, I have a floating number and when it has a leading zero such as `0.125`, when I convert it to string, I want the leading zero dropped. Result: `.125`

Thanks!

Edit:

More examples:

```
0.725  -> ".725"
1.5    -> "1.500"
0.125  -> ".125"
2.456 -> "2.456"
```

Potential Solution:

I take the first character in the string and if it is a zero, I merely set it to an empty character.

```
def remove_leading_zero string
  string[0] = "" if string[0] == "0"
  string
end
```

Comment: add more examples of input and desired output

Comment: Do you expect values like `1.725`? `-0.725`? How would you want them output? AFAIK there is no format to drop the leading zero.

Comment: I would like to drop the leading zero.

Comment: Should 2.4567 be truncated ("2.456") or rounded ("2.457") ?

Comment: @okysabeni would you like to drop leading zeros for negative numbers, too? For example, should `-0.725` be converted to `"-.725"`?

Comment: Not needed in my case Stefan but that will be a nice solution.

Comment: Eric. I made a type. I already use round(3) on my floating numbers. I just want to take that decimal number and drop the leading zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

You can use :

```
format('%.3f', value).sub(/^0/, '')
```

It removes the first character if it is a 0 followed by a dot.

## Test

```
values = [
  0.725,
  1.5,
  0.125,
  2.4567,
  0,
  10
]

values.each do |value|
  p format('%.3f', value).sub(/^0/, '')
end

#=>
# ".725"
# "1.500"
# ".125"
# "2.457"
# ".000"
# "10.000"
```

Comment: Or just `sub(/^0/, '')` – with `%.3f`, a leading zero is always followed by a dot.

Comment: True, I was trying to avoid replacing '0' with an empty string, but it cannot happen with `%.3f`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .to_s method to convert to string then .sub to substitute the proceeding 0:

```
number = 0.725
puts number.to_s.sub(/[0.]{2}/, '.')
#=> .725

number = -0.725
puts number.to_s.sub(/[0.]{2}/, '.')
#=> -.725
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `100` or `10.0`, but  I think you could fix that by using `/\b0\./`

Answer (score 0):

Let you contain value on `number`. You can use the following code for getting your expected output

```
str = "#{"%.3f" % number}"
str = str[1..-1] if str[0] == '0'
```

The above code will produce

```
0.725  -> ".725"
1.5    -> "1.500"
0.125  -> ".125"
2.4567 -> "2.456"
```